# Developing a virtual drive for windows (.net C#)

Tags: dokan

My requirement.

Develop a ntfs/fat formatable raw virtual drive in windows - something like truecrypt. I want to know if there is C# implementation for this somewhere.

dokan, callbackfs etc dont exactly fit since the file system itself has to be implemented. filedisk, imdisk etc are in kernel space and the code appears to be complex.

Something like callbackdisk or the one provided by eterlogic is perfect, but unfortunately they are expensive, and I don't want to buy them just for a small project.

Is there any other freely available alternative like the above two. Preferably a simple C# wrapper that provide read()/write() callback functions in userland that I can code.

Comment: Non-commercial licenses are offered for CallbackDisk.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution, but you need a folder for that :/
Just look here and see if it fits your desires: 
http://dotnet-snippets.de/snippet/erstellung-eines-virtuellen-laufwerks/712
It's in german, but you should see the div w/ the code.
The comments aren't that important.
Hope I helped you. :)